# iOS app not available for internal testing in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xamarin, testflight, ipa

I created a new iOS app in iTunes Connect and I am attempting to upload a build of my Xamarin app for internal testing via TestFlight.  I am unable to make the app available to testers because the build seems to disappear from the TestFlight tab.

After uploading the build via Application Loader, the build completes processing and is initially available on the TestFlight tab.

[image: 01-TestFlight]

When I click on the build, I am taken to the build details with the option to provide export compliance information.

[image: 02-compliance]

I enter the compliance information and select Start Internal Testing.

[image: 03-compliance]

I am then taken back to the build information screen with the build in a state of "Ready to Submit."

[image: 04-ready to submit]

At this point, if I click on the TestFlight tab to refresh the screen, the build is no longer listed under my version number.  I cannot find the build on the TestFlight tab to make it available for internal testing.

[image: 05-missing]

The build still appears on the Activity tab, and it can be selected as a build to submit it to the App Store as part of a release submission.  However, it is nowhere to be found on the TestFlight tab.

[image: 06-activity]

Am I missing a step in the process of making the build available on TestFlight for internal testing?

Comment: I had the same issue recently and I believe that the way to fix it was in the AppStore tab click on the "Version or Platform" and select iOS. There create a new version with the exact version number you are uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded.mobileprovision profile in the generated .ipa was missing the beta-reports-active key in its Entitlements.

After regenerating the iOS Distribution provisioning profile through Apple's Developer Portal, the behavior stopped and the builds were available for testing via TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

I generated one more build having AppStore build specified, uploaded it to iTunes connect and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Regenerating the provisioning profiles worked for us. cheers jkh